# Make IAlert as Observer

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, design-patterns

I'm using last selenium some websites have randomly popup messages that stops the normally test process

What i'm thinking is that i need to do IAlert as Observer pattern that catches the alert accept it and continue the test from the point that its stopped for handling the popup.

**IAlert Code:**

```
try
{
    IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    if (alert != null)
    {
        alert.Accept();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

The main question is how can i perform it or if there is a better way to handle randomly popups?

Thank's

Comment: How do you think the end user of the site you're testing will feel about these random popups?

Comment: @AndrewRegan it's automatic test, users not interactive.

Comment: Obviously, but the site you're testing is intended for a user to see?

Comment: @AndrewRegan no, it's running on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since popup would matter when you are trying to do something else, I will suggest the following approach: [EventFiringWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fa067c7b80f2e07270b7e36d2a01938aa3f33973/dotnet/src/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriver.cs) allows you to define custom code that will run right before or after a particular event. See an example [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fa067c7b80f2e07270b7e36d2a01938aa3f33973/dotnet/test/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriverTest.cs#L31).

Unfortunately I didn't write anything on .Net for a long time, so my C# skills are rusty. So roughly it would look like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
// add all relevant events, for example before clicking on something:
eventDriver.ElementClicking = new EventHandler<FindElementEventArgs>(checkPopup);
driver = eventDriver; // only need EventFiringWebDriver
```

And then

```
static void checkPopup(object sender, OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events. WebElementEventArgs e) {
     EventFiringWebDriver driver = (sender as OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver);
     try {
         Alert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
         alert.accept();
     }
     catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) { 
         // nothing to do - just continue
     }
}
```

So now, every time script is about to click something, it would first check for popup and accept it if needed.

Comment: sounds great exactly what i looked for, thanks i will try it.

Comment: ElementClicking is not so good idea better in exception thrown (ElementClicking will down the program efficiency minimum  to O(2N))