# Chrome SSO Popup detect programmatically

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java-Selenium to achieve automation of web pages and when I run test cases I get a popup in chrome browser to select a Certificate and I would like to know how can we detect if any Browser popup to select certificate is present so that I can do something about it.

I would like to get to know when any browser popup comes for selection of Certificate in Java-Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();       
    string message = alert.getText();

    // accept alert
    alert.accept();

} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
}
```

Comment: I am trying to find if any alert popped up (how to detect if any alert comes in between)

Comment: Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();  // will check if it is a popup if yes it will go on if not it will jump to exception

Comment: Or you want something like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536924/make-ialert-as-observer

Comment: yes something of this sort in Java-Selenium code I am trying to achieve.