# Selenium capture webpage exceptions/errors?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, web-testing

I am using Selenium with C# and NUnit to create a test framework for a web application platform.

The platform can throw exception if something goes wrong.

I am wondering that is there a way for browser/page to notify Selenium that an exception is thrown so I can use selenium to capture and record the exception instead of keeping Selenium checking web page and js console?

Comment: You can use EventFiringWebDriver, where you hook check for errors to events where it makes sense. I answered a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536924/make-ialert-as-observer/35544436#35544436 (in your case the "popup" part does not apply, but general structure does)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll check it out

Comment: I'm wondering that when exception is thrown, page will send msg to server. Can page send msg to Selenium as well so that Selenium can catch the error message?

Comment: "msg to Selenium": to whom exactly though? nobody's listening